# Java conventions, комментирование

Tags: java, комментарии, javadoc

Мне непонятен этот пункт:

> Block comments can start with `/*-`, which is recognized by `indent(1)` as the beginning of a block comment that should not reformatted. Example:
>
> ```
> /*
>  * Here is a block comment with some very special
>  * formatting that I want indent(1) to ignore.
>  *
>  * one
>  *    two
>  *       three
>  */
> ```
>
> Note: If you don’t use `indent(1)`, you don’t have to use `/*-` in your code or make any other concessions to the possibility that someone else might run `indent(1)` on your code.

Тут говорится о том, что комментарий, который не должен переформатироваться автоматически, должен начинаться с `/*`, но так все комментарии и начинаются, которые не являются необходимыми для документирования.

Как правильно должен быть оформлен комментарий, который потом не будет изменен автоматически, если он не по правилам?

Comment: Точно `/*`, а не `/**` в первой строке?

Comment: @Qwertiy, точно. Можете сами открыть Java Code Conventions, чтобы убедиться. Оно небольшое, сразу найдете.

Comment: Javadoc [пишется](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80) с двойной звёздочкой.

Comment: Хм.. Кажется они вообще о каком-то переформатировании исходника говорят. Что такое `indent(1)`?

Comment: Если вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый (плюсик и галочка слева от ответа)

Comment: @Qwertiy может тут и ошибка, вот я и хочу разобраться. indent(1) - как я поняла, это то что строчки идут лесенкой. Что будет в java-доке, эти отступы сохранятся? Эти три строчки ведь приобретут равнение слева. Они будут по одной линии начинаться.

Answer (score 1):

Комментарии бывают двух разных типов:

```
// однострочный комментарий
```

и

```
/*
многострочный
комментарий
*/
```

Разницы между ними нет (кроме того, что первый - однострочный, а второй - многострочный), а обязательное оформление я вам показал.

Как сделать так чтобы комментарий не исправлялся, я не знаю. Возможно даже нельзя это сделать.

Comment: Бывает еще и 3-й вид комментариев `/**..... */` - Javadoc комментарии

Comment: спасибо за дополнение

Comment: Это я знаю, спасибо, но вопрос не об этом, а том, какой должен быть комментарий, который потом не будет изменен при автоматическом форматировании.

Comment: А вам что нужно, чтобы он был по-другому? Вы код комментируете что ли?

Comment: я отредактировал ответ

Answer (score 1):

См. [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language: 5. Comments](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-comments.html):

> В Java-программах могут быть два вида комментариев: комментарии к реализации и комментарии к документации. Комментарии к реализации - это комментарии, унаследованные из `C++`, которые разделяются символами `/*...*/` и `//`. Комментарии к документации (также известные как *javadoc*) предназначены только для Java и разделяются символами `/**...*/`. Эти комментарии можно извлечь в HTML-файлы с помощью специального инструмента.

Например, откроем исходный код класса [`java.lang.String`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java). Сверху идёт многострочный комментарий `/*...*/` об авторских правах, далее перед самим классом и перед его методами идут *javadoc*, также по коду встречаются однострочные комментарии `//`.
В [онлайн докумнтацию HTML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) попадает только *javadoc*, другие комментарии не попадают.

При переформатировании кода, однострочные и многострочные комментарии изменяться не будут - изменится только *javadoc*, внутри можно использовать разметку HTML.